# issues with UART communication and a PIC processor

Tags: uart

I have been working on enabling UART transmission between my PIC18f4620, a FT232, and my flash tool of choice.

Hardware wise - I don't see anything out of the ordinary (see below)
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7SlB.jpg)
[image: This is the circuit for the project.]

Yet with the provided code[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/knuVZ.jpg) I am unable to receive anything other than ? in the COM receive section. This behavior is matched within coolterm as well. I have ensured the Tx/Rx are indeed flipped between the FT232 and the PIC processor, and I have double checked the baud rate matches the 10MHz crystal, still no dice. Any insight would be greatly! Thank you!

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/knuVZ.jpg)
[image]

[image]

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/knuVZ.jpg)

```
const unsigned char MSG0[] = "Transmitting... ";
const unsigned char MSG1[] = "Sent:";

// Subroutine Declarationsb
#include <pic18.h>

// Subroutines
#include        "lcd_portd.c"

#include <delays.h>
#include <plib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void UART_TX_Init(void)
{

  BRGH = 1; // Set For High-Speed Baud Rate
  SPBRG = 65; // Set The Baud Rate To Be 9600 bps
  //--[ Enable The Ascynchronous Serial Port ]--
  SYNC = 0;
  SPEN = 1;
  //--[ Set The RX-TX Pins to be in UART mode (not io) ]--
  TRISC6 = 1;  // As stated in the datasheet
  TRISC7 = 1;  // As stated in the datasheet
  TXEN = 1; // Enable UART Transmission
  
}

void UART_Writes(uint8_t data)
{
  while(!TRMT);
  TXREG = data;
}


void UART_Write_Text(char *text)
{
  int i;
  for(i=0;text[i]!='\0';i++)
      UART_Writes(text[i]);
}

 uint8_t UART_TX_Empty()
{
  // Check the output (transmitter) buffer emptiness
  return TRMT;
}

void Wait(unsigned int X)
{
   unsigned int i, j;

   for (i=0; i<X; i++)
      for (j=0; j<609; j++);
   }

         
// Main Routine

void main(void)
{
UART_TX_Init();

unsigned int result = 0;
   unsigned int i;
   unsigned char C1, C16, C256;
   uint8_t Data = 1;
   TRISA = 0;
   TRISC = 0;
   TRISB = 0;
   TRISD = 0;
   TRISE = 0;
   TRISA = 0;
   TRISB = 0xff;
   PORTC = 0;
   PORTD = 0;
   PORTE = 0;

   ADCON1 = 0x0F;

   LCD_Init();                  // initialize the LCD

   LCD_Move(0,0);  for (i=0; i<20; i++) LCD_Write(MSG0[i]); 
   Wait_ms(100); 
   LCD_Move(1,0);  for (i=0; i<5; i++) LCD_Write(MSG1[i]); 
   while(1) {

if(RB0){
uint8_t Data = 1;
Wait_ms(100); 
LCD_Move(1,5); LCD_Out(Data,1,0);
} 
if(!RB0){
uint8_t Data = 0;
TXREG = Data;
Wait_ms(100); 
LCD_Move(1,5); LCD_Out(Data,1,0);
}

UART_Writes(Data);

    }

}
```

[EDIT]
Configuration Bits
[image]

This project is coded using MPLAB IDE v8.92

Comment: Can you show your configuration bits? Which IDE are you using?

Comment: @Reinderien I have updated the post to include both the IDE as well as the configuration bits

Comment: How many decoupling caps do you have?

Comment: @filo 1, 47uF 50v cap